# How can I transform data to image?

Tags: iphone, transform, nsdata, cfnetwork

i learning CFNetwork , socket, i almost completed. But, I want to use UIImageView, so that 
receive data from URL, then transform to UIImage , then add UIImageView

but i think that it has a problem about transform data to image

i use below code...

```
void CFSockCallBack(CFSocketRef s, CFSocketCallBackType callbackType, CFDataRef address, const void *data, void *info){

     if (callbackType == kCFSocketDataCallBack) {
        UInt8 *d = (UInt8 *)CFDataGetBytePtr((CFDataRef)data);
        int len = CFDataGetLength((CFDataRef) data);

         NSData *nsdata = [NSData dataWithBytes:d length:len];

         imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 460.0)];
         UIImage *receiveImage = [UIImage imageWithData:nsdata];
```

imageView is instance delcared static .

do you  understand my coding? T.T  then
Plz help me!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you setting the imageView's image property to the receiveImage? Or that was only accidentally left out of the code snippet? Also are you getting some sort of error message or only a blank UIImageView space?

Comment: First, thanks for answer . Yes, that code just left out of the code snippet. I was declared UIImageView to static, and alloc too. but i don't know how to add UIImageView in self.window . when i added


[self.window addsubView:imageView];
[imageView initWithImage:receiveImage];
but that have error! 
--> 'self' undeclared (first use in this function)



I think that because that function is callBack method.
how can i do ? ;

Comment: Not really sure about the self.window part,try it with self.view instead maybe and see if it works.